# How to clear all intent variable on pressing back button?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm having Android application which has 3 activity in it A, B and C.

When application starts it launches the activity A its display list on information.

When user selects an item from the list , the selected list item information is passed to the activity B using `intent.putextra(string variable)`. Activity B displays data based on selection.

When I press back button from B and come to A , and again select new item from the list still, the old selected item is in the string variable.

I've tried the following code but it is not working.

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        selected="";     
    }
```

`selected` is my string variable.

Comment: if you simply want to display data, then why are you doing this startActivityforResult, startActivity would be enough

Comment: why you are using `onActivityResult()`?

Comment: @JaiSoni because i have searched on and find that its a way to clear variable.

Answer (score -1):

for this case no need to use startActivityForResult . startActivity() could solved your problem.

Comment: I have used only start activity, but don't able to get the appropriate result.

Comment: could you post your code to let us know how you've done ?

Comment: I have created a temporary variable on onCreate method and make it null.